# iTunes Connect Invalid Pre-Release Train.

Tags: ios, ios8, app-store-connect

I received the following error in Xcode when attempting to submit an app archive:

ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Pre-Release Train. The train version '2.1.5' is closed for new build submissions"

[image: An Image showing the iTunes Connect error]

Does anyone have a solution for this?  This version was already waiting for review.  I rejected it and now am trying to submit a new build.  Same version number but I have incremented the build number.

Comment: Same here. Feels like this a bug with itunesconnect. Between Xcode 6 and new iTunesconnect this whole submission process is now @!#%!@# up.

Comment: I agree with this new update a lot has changed at both ends... but thank goodness stackOverFlow always saves the day for me

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I had to change the version number in Xcode to 2.1.6 and create a new archive in order for iTunes connect to accept the upload.  However, it still allowed me to add the build to the 2.1.5 release.

Comment: in i tunse connect you can see all your uploaded bealds. It just conflicting.

Comment: @Bimawa yes.I can see all uploaded builds in prerelease.but when I choose a build,the option still be the older one.:-(

Comment: @CashLee李秉骏 strange behavior, try reset cookies in safari.

Comment: @PiotrTomasik If it allowed you to add the build to the 2.1.5 release, what was the point of you updating the version in Xcode to 2.1.6? Could you be bit more specific please? Are you saying that once you changed the version to 2.1.6, it let you upload a binary to that version but then also let you upload to 2.1.5? Because that doesn't seem like it should be possible, as the version name needs to be greater than or equal to the latest, unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 4):

Just had a similar situation - without the error code. 
I changed the version number in iTunes Connect, built another archive with the new version number. Tried again and submission passed.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing the version on iTune Connect and try one more time. This work for me.

Answer (score 3):

This is serious bug on Apple version platform.

Without adding a new version. I changed the version number in app information, amazingly it has taken the change.

I uploaded the new build and with the same version number. It has accepted the build.