# App Store Connect giving me 'Invalid Pre-Release Train'

Tags: app-store-connect, fastlane

Uploading through Fastlane gives me the following:

```
Making sure the latest version on App Store Connect matches '1.1.0' from the ipa file...
'1.1.0' is the latest version on App Store Connect
Uploading metadata to App Store Connect
Successfully uploaded set of metadata to App Store Connect
Starting with the upload of screenshots...
Successfully uploaded screenshots to App Store Connect
Uploading binary to App Store Connect
Going to upload updated app to App Store Connect
This might take a few minutes. Please don't interrupt the script.
iTunes Transporter successfully finished its job
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Successfully uploaded package to App Store Connect. It might take a few minutes until it's visible online.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished the upload to App Store Connect
```

But then I get a message from App Store Connect with the following:

```
Invalid Pre-Release Train - The train version '1.1' is closed for new build submissions
```

Here's what it looks like within App Store Connect:
[image]

I read [iTunes Connect Invalid Pre-Release Train.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030285/itunes-connect-invalid-pre-release-train), but the solution there seems to be updating the version name. The thing is I had already done this. v1.1.0 like you see in the image above used to be v1.02. It automatically turned to v1.1.0 in App Store Connect as a result of the version name in my Info.plist. But the binary still got rejected.

What do I need to do to get it uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

Update the version to 1.1.1. You may want to start using fastlane’s increment_version_number action instead of trying to do this manually.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I'll try this. Although I don't know why it rejected 1.1.0 to begin with. Regarding `increment_version_number`, I have considered using this, but given the current project structure, it would be redundant, as there's no changelog, and so specifying whether it's a patch, minor, or major update via the `bump_type` parameter is the same effort as changing the version manually.

Comment: I think it was rejected because it considers `1.1` and `1.1.0` to be equivalent. If you ignore `bump_type` it will just bump the `patch`. `increment_version_number` will keep your version number in sync between your primary target, test target, and any app extensions like notification, Siri, etc.

Comment: Even if it sees them as equivalent, I don’t see why it would reject. 1.1.0 currently is at state ‘Prepare for submission’; meaning I should be able to upload builds for it. Definitely seems like a bug with App Store Connect. The public release should be 1.1.0. Will have to waste a patch version for nothing... :)